# Отсутствие тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: тире

В предложении: «Говорить об этом сейчас все равно что обсуждать, как красивы мыльные пузыри...». Верно ли отсутствие тире перед «все равно»?

Answer (score 2):

*Говорить об этом сейчас – **все равно что** обсуждать, как красивы мыльные пузыри..*

ВСЁ РАВНО  ЧТО в данном случае является единой конструкцией – связкой или союзом.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_807

1. Если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены именительным падежом существительного, тире перед этой связкой обычно не ставится, но может быть поставлено при наличии паузы.  Греки ведь всё равно что армяне или цыгане. Рафаэль в живописи – всё равно как Суворов в военном деле.
2. Если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены инфинитивами, то перед связкой ставится тире. Спасать его – всё равно что грести против течения в потоке, в котором несутся все.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Таким образом, сочетание "все равно что" ведет себя как сравнительный союз в обычных правилах Розенталя п. 1. (Примечание об отсутствие знака или факультативном тире при наличии союза, если оба главных члена  выражены сущ. в форме И.п.) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92
2. Но примечание не распространяется на тот случай, если хотя бы один главный член выражен инфинитивом, поэтому постановка тире считается обязательной как у Розенталя, так и в пприведенной статье из Справочника по пунктуации.