# Почему нет тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым при наличии вводного слова?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

***Быть рядом с женщиной, конечно, великая честь для мужчины, но всё же в круглосуточном режиме это утомительно.***

Можно ли  по правилам  Розенталя  (или правилам ПАС) объяснить отсутствие тире в предложении, где один из главных членов (в данном случае подлежащее) выражено **инфинитивом.**

Очевидно, что тире здесь не ставится при наличии **вводного слова**, но в правилах указано, что это допускается  в том случае, если оба главных члена выражены **сущ. в И.п.**

Таким образом, имеет место **несоответствие  знаков препинания формальным правилам**. Но как тогда объяснить отсутствие тире? Получается, что формулировка этого правила **не полностью корректна?**

**Теория** этого  вопроса обсуждалась недавно, поэтому  нет смысла делать это еще раз:  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463103/Отсутствие-тире-между-подлежащим-и-сказуемым/463108#463108](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463103/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC/463108#463108)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** ОТ 25.01.2021

Уважаемые друзья,  мне очень хотелось бы **услышать ваше мнение**  при обсуждении данного вопроса,  хотелось бы прочитать и **другие ответы**. А также внимательно посмотрите,  какой ответ вы поддерживаете, за какой отдаете свои голоса.

*Каждому издательству по справочнику? Правила не являются законом, это сугубо рекомендательное руководство. Пишите как  нравится, никто не принуждает вас следовать правилам.*

Вы тоже так думаете? Да только что мы тогда здесь обсуждаем, для чего собрались? Есть ли у нашего форума какие-то **традиции**,  «*а так же узко-специальные правила, относящиеся к около-языковым аспектам работы*»?

Comment: Можно так: "Быть рядом с женщиной - это, конечно, великая честь для мужчины, но всё же в круглосуточном режиме это утомительно.". Но как сказал JKlen непонятно к чему относить вводное слово, к сказуемому или ко всему предложению.

Answer (score 3):

> Очевидно, что тире здесь не ставится при наличии **вводного слова**, но в правилах указано, что это допускается в том случае, если оба главных члена выражены **сущ. в И.п.**

Как я понимаю, вы говорите о §79.1 из Розенталя<sup>1</sup>:

> §79. 1. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в именительном падеже.
>
> (...)
>
> Тире обычно не ставится, хотя подлежащее и сказуемое выражены именительным падежом существительного:
>
> (...)
>
> 4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, наречие, союз, частица.

Поскольку упоминаний аналогичного случая с подлежащим, выраженным инфинитивом, у Розенталя нет, то правило, действительно, предполагает наличие тире в вашем примере.

Однако, если взять свод из "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>2</sup>, то там указывается другая формулировка:

> §15. Тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым не ставится:
>
> (...)
>
> 6. Если между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица.

Обратите внимание, что тут нет явного требования к форме подлежащего: достаточно чтобы именное сказуемое было выражено существительным.

То есть, отвечая на ваш вопрос: согласно одному набору правил, тире здесь ставить нужно, а согласно другому—нельзя.

Далее приведу мои размышления.

На мой взгляд, "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" приводят более правильную формулировку, поскольку наличие и тире, и вводного слова сделали бы фразу куда сложнее для восприятия вне зависимости от того чем именно выражены члены предложения. Я даже не уверен, где поставить тире в такой фразе.

Например, в вашей фразе, *конечно* характеризует доносимую информацию как достоверный факт. Однако к самой информации оно не имеет никакого отношения и при восприятии непосредственного факта, содержащегося в высказывании, оно вычленяется:

*Быть рядом с женщиной [, конечно,] великая честь для мужчины, но всё же в круглосуточном режиме это утомительно.*

Для меня проблема в том, что и вводное слово, и тире занимают одно и то же место в предложении: пробел между *женщиной* и *великая*.

Можно было бы сказать, что *конечно* должно идти перед тире:

*Быть рядом с женщиной, конечно — великая честь для мужчины, но всё же в круглосуточном режиме это утомительно.*

Но теперь семантика фразы становится крайне сложной для понимания: означает ли наличие тире, что *конечно* нужно относить только к первой половине фразы?

Аналогичная проблема возникает, если тире идет перед вводным словом.

Оформлять *конечно* тире с двух сторон тоже не принято (да и правила не предполагают возможности выделения одиночных вводных слов тире), и это выглядит скорее как вставка.

Поэтому вариант без тире, на мой взгляд, является самым простым и безопасным с точки зрения письменной речи.

Я помню, что вы предпочитаете руководствоваться интонациями устной речи при обосновании правописания, поэтому приведу и такой аргумент: употребление *конечно* напрочь останавливает течение оригинальной фразы и полностью перекрывает интонационную подводку под тире. Поэтому можно считать, что и на письме мы опускаем пунктуацию между подлежащим и сказуемым, заполняя её место пунктуацией вводной конструкции.

---

1. Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию, М.: ЧеРо, 1999.
2. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, свое мнение по поводу ПАС я высказала в комментарии

Answer (score 1):

Это комментарий к ответу.

ПАС приводит более правильную формулировку? **Что-то я сомневаюсь**, давайте почитаем: «Тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым **не ставится**: 6. Если **между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным** стоит **вводное слово**, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица».

**Категоричное, однако,  утверждение.**. Недавно я прочитала  такую фразу: «Он не любил категоричных суждений. Этот вид правды **ближе всего ко лжи**». Проверим?

Беру любое предложение, например: ***Думать оригинально – большое искусство***. Вставляю туда вводное слово, беру два варианта предложений  и записываю их **по слуху**.

(1)  *Думать оригинАльно – **вероятно**, большое искУсство.*

(2) *Думать оригинально,  **вероятно**, большОе искусство, но любители всегда нахОдятся.*

(Примеры ни в коем случае не относятся к конкретной ситуации, они совершенно случайны.)

**Могу я именно так оформить эти  предложения?** Если да, то это будет несоответствие правилам ПАС.

Comment: Да вы не расстраивайтесь так, это же просто дружеский разговор и определенное к вам доверие  (можно было ограничиться короткой фразой: спасибо за ваше мнение). Я просто искренне огорчена  несовершенством тех «стандартизованных» форм, которые  нам предлагаются.  Если я уважаю законы и хочу им следовать,  то  как мне это сделать? По РОЗЕНТАЛЮ? Там тире нужно ставить ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО, хотя  ни одного примера с инфинитивом и вводным словом не приведено. По ЛОПАТИНУ? У него тоже нет примеров, а тире ЗАПРЕЩАЕТСЯ ставить.

Comment: И  КАТЕГОРИЧНОСТЬ – это не только красивая цитата, но и недостаток формулировки любого правила:  вот какое ни возьми, на него обязательно найдется исключение.  И любое суждение является истиной только в определенных границах – простейшая философия. Да и правила – НЕ РЕКОМЕНДАТЕЛЬНОЕ руководство, как вы считаете.  Если, к примеру,  вы  пойдете работать редактором или корректором, то должны будете следовать  этим правилам БУКВАЛЬНО и обоснованность каждого знака ДОКАЗЫВАТЬ, потому что иначе нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Даже и *не знаю-не знаю* (так нельзя писать — но я следую **утверждению** участника *JKlen*’а: «Это—авторское написание»), стоит ли высказывать *собственное* мнение по *спорному* вопросу.

[Утверждение ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=52) (Лопатин):
**Тире** между подлежащим и именным сказуемым **не ставится**:
6. Если между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица: *Грач, **конечно**, птица умная и самостоятельная, но голоса у него нет* (Пауст.)...

Другое утверждение, не менее категоричное ([Тире при подлежащем и / или сказуемом, выраженным инфинитивом](https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=56)):
Везде постановка тире **обязательна**.
Это пример правила, основанного на последовательно проведенном структурном принципе, исключений из которого не бывает.

*Быть рядом с женщиной, конечно, **великая** честь для мужчины, но всё же в круглосуточном режиме это **утомительно.***
Смысл: честь, конечно же, *великая*, но — *утомительная* в круглосуточном режиме. О понятии, собственно, чести никто и не рассуждает — она воспринимается как само собой разумеющееся (см. [**контекст**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=GXKZFWlHJ0AC&pg=PT108&lpg=PT108&dq=%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE.&source=bl&ots=0uj8dzuZCp&sig=ACfU3U2bhI8CgLooHEweh2tAsnNT2zYu3A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB89iN-bfuAhWtAxAIHdUHAvcQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE.&f=false)).

Ставим тире:
*Быть рядом с женщиной — конечно, великая **честь** для мужчины, но всё же в круглосуточном режиме это утомительно.*
Смысл смещается на то, что именно *нахождение* рядом с женщиной есть *честь*: и уже неважно, какая она там — утомительная или нет.

Можно было выбрать и такой вариант (без ломания копий).
**Быть рядом с женщиной, конечно, честь для мужчины великая, но всё же — в круглосуточном режиме — утомительная.**

P. S. А вот ещё предложения, навскидку найденные мною у этого автора ([Д. Емец. Мефодий Буслаев. Книга Семи Дорог](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=17894&p=10)). Надо их править? Думаю, надо.

> Рюкзак валялся на полу, все его содержимое было раскидано по лифту. Меф спрятал катар и стал ползать по полу, торопливо и без разбора забрасывая вещи обратно. *Он еще не закончил, когда лифт добрался до двадцать первого этажа и, отдуваясь, раздвинул двери.* [Нет запятой — лифт отдувался?]

> В этой части проникновенного монолога **на него** стали вопить и колотить подушкой.