# Почему используется одно тире для обособления вставной конструкции?

Tags: тире, ссп, вставная-конструкция

Почему вставная конструкция в этом предложении выделена одним, а не двумя  тире?

*Пассажиры не слишком взволновались — **остановка поезда по техническим причинам была делом обычным,** но Филату это не понравилось.*

Или здесь нужно применять другое правило? Есть ли у  Розенталя или в ПАС примеры такого оформления?

Comment: Запятую же в любом случае придется ставить, тогда получится " , – ". А если опустить тире, то простая запятая будет попроще и читаться, и смотреться

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. У вас интересный подход к решению задач.  Вероятно, до принятия Свода правил в 1956 году и их дальнейшей проработки Розенталем и другими лингвистами можно было ориентироваться не то, что проще читается и смотрится. Это вполне соответсвует назначению знаков препиания, но сейчас все решения должны быть согласованы с правилами. И вот по правилам Розенталя для обособления вводных конструкций предлагается два тире (пункт 4) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125  Почему здесь только одно тире? Может быть, здесь не вставная конструкция, как определить грамматику?

Comment: И  еще можно вопрос? Как вы думаете, варианты с одним тире и двумя тире будут читаться одинаково или по-разному?  И семантика при этом меняется или нет?  Если ориентироваться не на правила, а на слух или на интуицию,  то каждое решение должно иметь какое-то обоснование. Если же стремиться только к ПРОСТОТЕ, то можно  сделать язык примитивным, лишить его тонкостей и оттенков в передаче смысла.

Comment: Автор текста, видимо, использовал не вставную конструкцию, а причинно-следственную связь. Но если учитывать современные правила в данном примере и поставить верное двоеточие вместо тире, то какой будет пунктуация в продолжении предложения после части, следующей за двоеточием? "Пассажиры не слишком взволновались: остановка поезда по техническим причинам была делом обычным, - но Филату это не понравилось". Правильно? Если да, есть ли ссылки на авторитетные источники с похожими примерами?

Comment: А вам нравится ваше оформление?  Красиво выглядит, удобно читать? Мне вот не очень, у автора было лучше.  Зачем нам два сильных знака, они только запутывают читателя.  Знаки нужно для ясности, для легкости понимания, для графической эстетики, в конце концов. Нельзя, чтобы они царапали и раздражали наше сознание, даже если они поставлены по правилам. Значит, мы неправильно читаем и понимаем эти правила.  В п.3 из комментария 1 я уже писала следующее: БСП с неоднородными взаимообусловленными отношениями – это всегда двухчастная конструкция.

Comment: Это означает, что бессоюзная связь делит предложение на две фразы,   в одном предложении не может быть двух бессоюзных связей, обозначенных тире и двоеточием. Это важно понять, потому что  при наличии только союзной связи деление на три части возможно.  В БСП же  смысловые отношения выражены не союзом, а интонацией, мы можем  по слуху определить эти отношения только в двухчастной конструкции.  Но и это еще не всё.  Если мы захотим  добавить  к бессоюзной связи союзную связь (союз НО), то и это не получится. Такое предложение мы тоже не сможем прочитать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос заинтересовал меня сразу, как только появился. Погуглив, я открыл новое для себя имя Дмитрий Емец. Вот полный абзац из его книги «[Последний стожар](https://knizhnik.org/dmitrij-emets/poslednij-stozhar/1)»:

> Филат доехал до «Тверской», перешёл на «Пушкинскую» и, убедившись, что хвоста за ним нет, сел на поезд в сторону «Щукинской». На первом же перегоне поезд внезапно встал в тоннеле и свет в вагонах погас. **Пассажиры не слишком взволновались — остановка поезда по техническим причинам была делом обычным, но Филату это не понравилось.** Он заметил несколько зеленоватых искр, скользнувших по толстой оплётке кабелей тоннеля.

Прочитав ответы, один из которых является комментарием, я запутался в терминологии. Меня смущает пункт 3 в комментарии, а именно: "...отношение между частями [БСП] вполне определенные (пояснительные, изъяснительные, противительные, присоединительные и т. д.)...". Чем часть рассматриваемого предложения до союза ***но*** отличается, например, от предложения ***А углубляться мы не могли — земля промёрзла*** (Гран.), приведенного в параграфе Розенталя "[ДВОЕТОЧИЕ — ТИРЕ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189)" в качестве БСП? И там, и там мы видим пояснение, причинно-следственные связи... (Здесь я чувствую возражения, но пока рассуждаю и ничего не утверждаю.) Также я согласен с тем, что в предложении из вопроса часть после тире больше выглядит как присоединение. А вот вставной конструкцией ее назвать не получается.

В параграфе Розенталя "[ВСТАВНЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ И СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЯ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)" есть такой пример:

> *Смеялся он мало — **настолько у него хватало чувства такта,** — но всё же насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах* — вторая часть начинается с союза, перед которым должна быть запятая...

В этом примере мы легко можем удалить вставку, и семантика остается на месте. В нашем же случае грамматика остается (это ССП), но смысл теряется. Филату же не понравилось не то, что пассажиры не слишком взволновались, и не причина этой невзволнованности (ух как много ***не***). Ему не понравилось то, о чем говорится в предыдущем предложении: "*На первом же перегоне поезд внезапно встал в тоннеле и свет в вагонах погас*".

С одной стороны, как простого читателя, меня всё устраивает: текст несложный, смысл прочитывается. Но с другой, педантичной, стороны, на месте автора я бы вместо ***но*** нарисовал союз ***а***. Как ни крути, это ***но*** не вписывается в семантику, даже если перед ним поставить точку. А с ***а*** серединное предложение будет полноправной вставкой, обозначенной двумя тире по правилам: ***Пассажиры не слишком взволновались — остановка поезда по техническим причинам была делом обычным, — а Филату это не понравилось.***

Хотя я не писатель. Я только учусь.

Answer (score 1):

Это не вставная и не вводная конструкция, а придаточная часть сложного бессоюзного предложения. Она находится в причинно-следственных отношениях с главной частью и отделяется от неё двоеточием, а не тире (между частями можно вставить союз *потому что*).

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Здравствуйте, Парис де Ниша. Я помнила ваше имя и поэтому посмотрела профиль. Вы последний раз отвечали в 2013 году, и еще вы –  дипломированный филолог-русист. Поэтому я с интересом и вниманием прочитала  ваш ответ. Замечания у меня такие.

1. Сразу могу сказать, что это цитата из напечатанного художественного романа достаточно известного автора. **Тире там уже стоит,** меня же интересует причина, по которой отсутствует второе тире (**о двоеточии речи нет**). Кстати, причинно-следственные отношения можно обозначить как  тире, так и  двоеточием (Розенталь, пункт 4)  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189.
2. Теперь о сути вопроса. Если использовать **союз «потому что»,** то мы получим сложное предложение с подчинительной и сочинительной связью, состоящее из трех простых предложений.  **Это совсем другая грамматика,** не имеющая отношения к нашему предложению.
3. **Это не БСП, и вот почему.**  БСП с неоднородными взаимообусловленными отношениями – это всегда **двухчастная конструкция,**  отношение между частями  вполне определенные (пояснительные, изъяснительные, противительные, присоединительные  и т.д.), они обозначены тире или двоеточием.
4. **Это ССП с противительным союзом НО**  (Пассажиры не слишком взволновались,  но Филату это не понравилось) и  вставной или присоединительной конструкцией (остановка поезда по техническим причинам была делом обычным),  которая явно имеет **дополнительное**, а не основное значение.  **Я так понимаю  грамматику этого предложения.**
5. Примечание. Вы используете не очень ясную терминологию. Что означает **«придаточная и главная часть в БСП»**, такие части мы выделяем только в СПП.

И большое спасибо вам за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу 2**

1. Александр, опять я отвечаю именно для вас, осторожно посматривая по сторонам (будут бить или нет), вы-то меня точно бить не будете. Зачем я задала этот вопрос? **Это мое давнее желание увидеть в знаках их глубинный смысл, а не только оформление по инструкции.** В этой теме (вставные и присоединительные конструкции в середине сложного или осложненного предложения) сделать это  до конца так и **не получается**, то есть нужно соединить в единую концепцию **знаки, семантику, интонацию и существующие правила.**
2. **Со вставками** понятно следующее.  **Графически  и интонационно** они вычисляются четко: на письме **два обязательных тире**, а в устной речи  подчеркнутые **паузы и вставочная интонация** (произношение с общим понижением тона, иногда с изменением темпа речи). **С точки зрения семантики** – дополнительный характер сообщения, хотя здесь автор имеет возможность **выбора:**  он может перенести информацию  на второй план речи  или включить в основное содержание в качестве присоединения.

**А вот с правилами найти общий язык не очень получается.** Редакторы-корректоры берутся решать семантическую задачу самостоятельно: это дополнительные сведения, поэтому **будем оформлять как вставку.**

3. **С присоединительными конструкциями еще сложнее.** Графически это **одно тире**, а вот **интонация** до конца неясна. Если присоединение стоит **в  конце предложения**, то  присоединительное тире  соответствует полному понижению тона перед  паузой, а далее следует присоединительная конструкция со  своей интонацией (что зависит уже от сложности самой конструкции).

**Но в середине предложения ситуация другая**, так что приходится перестраиваться и подчиняться основной интонационной модели. В нашем предложении  это выглядит **как встроенная интонация:** присоединяемое предложение  самостоятельность теряет, отделяется только паузой, включается **в состав** основного предложения и используется как **его структурный элемент**. Теперь даже  **тоническое  ударение**  падает на конец общей фразы: «*Пассажиры не слишком взволновались — остановка поезда по техническим причинам была делом **обЫчным**, но Филату это не **понрАвилось***».

Основная граница при таком оформлении проходит  перед противительным союзом НО, выражая противопоставление **в двухчастной конструкции**. (При вставке мы имеем ту же самую конструкцию, просто вставку можно убрать, а произносится она на втором плане речи.)

4. **Так присоединить или перенести на второй план?** Здесь кажется, что лучше **соединить причину и следствие**, то есть поставить **одно тире**. А что говорят правила? Они вообще что-нибудь говорят? Такое оформление разрешается **для обособленных приложений,** но у нас-то не приложение. И  редактор, не найдя нужное правило (надо же на что-то сослаться), начнет предложение **править** и поставит **второе тире.**
5. Вот и вам хочется подобрать вариант, чтобы **иметь право** оформить предложение как вставку. А это уже вторжение в тонкую художественную ткань.

**Предлагаете убрать союз НО и написать союз А?** Ох уж эти противительные союзы! По ним меня постоянно консультирует синтаксический справочник, без него никуда. Итак, **союз А.** Значение **сопоставительное**: предметы из одного ряда различаются по каким-то признакам, но при этом **не противоречат** друг другу, а просто сосуществуют. В нашем случае союз А будет обозначать: на остановку поезда Филат и пассажиры реагируют по-разному.

**Союз НО.** Значение **противительное**: события противоречат друг другу, ограничивают действия друг друга, при уступительно-противительном значении вторая часть не соответствует естественному следствию событий. В нашем случае **Филат неестественно реагирует на остановку поезда**, подозревая в этом что-то необычное.  Пожалуй, **менять союзы нельзя**.

6. Таким образом, Александр, мы согласны с вами в главном: **знаки препинания – это нечто большее, чем оформительские знаки**. И в данном предложении одно тире действительно соответствует **присоединению,** а два тире – это именно **вставка**. Небольшое разночтение было **в семантике**, но это вполне естественно – люди вовсе не обязаны думать одинаково, у каждого свое восприятие текста.

Ну и бесконечно приятно было отметить ваш **непреходящий интерес к искусству словесности.** Право, оно этого стоит. **Магия слова** – это не просто образ, а **прямое значение** сказанного, почему бы вам не согласиться и с этим тоже, хотя вы еще «не писатель, а только учитесь» :)

**И большое спасибо вам за ответ!** Наверное, что-то еще можно было добавить, сейчас не вспомню, но остальное, может быть, прочитаете между строк.

Примечание.

1. На анализ БСП (пункт 3) места уже нет, но когда-нибудь обсудим и это.
2. А с Дмитрием Емецом хорошо бы вам познакомиться поближе. Это философия, психология, магия, сказка, тонкий мир и образная фантастика, соединенные вместе. И  все события происходят не где-нибудь, а рядом с нами, в наше время, у нас на глазах и в наших главных городах (Москве и Петербурге).
   У него интересный сериал "Мефодий Буслаев" (19 книг), а новый сериал он только начал (2 книги).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой обширный комментарий, лестные слова и оценку моего ответа. По правде говоря, на вопрос-то я не ответил, да и мне самому на слух больше нравится с союзом НО. Я думал, может, он относится сразу ко всей структуре, только не совсем понятно было, чему он противостоит. Язык – загадка.

Comment: @Sharon Замечательное, потрясное дело — восхищаться тонким миром и образной фантастикой! Не спорю. А как же ж то, что этому восхищению должно сопутствовать: правильная пунктуация и правильное согласование? ВЫ видите одно, а я  (бестолковая, наверно!) вижу совсем другое...

Comment: @Sharon Вот поэтому я и перестала отвечать на Ваши вопросы. (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463264/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0/463282#463282) _Зачем_ рядом с такой интересностью обычная правильность?

Answer (score 1):

А это небольшой ответ  моим критикам

Цитата: Замечательное дело — восхищаться тонким миром и образной фантастикой! Не спорю. А как же то, что этому восхищению должна сопутствовать **правильная пунктуация**? Зачем рядом с такой интересностью **обычная правильность**!

Ну что ж,  попробую высказать свое мнение об обычной правильности.

**Наша  с и с т е м а  пунктуации** – это нечто особенное,  уникальное,  она тесно связана с грамматикой, фонетикой и объективна по своей природе, также она строится по определенным законам и способна к саморазвитию.  В защите сама система  не нуждается,  а вот **понимание и изучение  ее принципов** пользователями русского письма является очень важным.

Надо хорошо представлять, что  правила  (в качестве **о п и с а н и я**  этой системы) еще **далеко не совершенны.** Да, после 1956 года была проведена большая работа, но она еще **не закончена, ее нужно продолжать.**  Разумеется, это должны делать специалисты, а утверждать – правительственная комиссия, но ведь думать над этой проблемой никому не запрещается.

Давайте будем помнить о том, что **практическая орфография** часто опережает  правила и способствует их развитию и изменению,  причем это мнение известных лингвистов.  Поэтому даже простые  наблюдения в этой области  могут быть полезными и интересными.

Мой вопрос был исключительно  **дискуссионным** и тоже был рассчитан на понимание, мне просто хотелось **найти обоснование** той форме написания, которая уже испльзуется в книге.

Поэтому и не ожидала  я столь **негативной реакции** от общества. Разве призываю я вас писать не по правилам? Посмотрите мои ответы, там практически везде даются **ссылки** на источники (Розенталь, ПАС или  ответы Грамоты. ру), частным учебным сайтам  я не очень доверяю. А многие ли еще так делают?

Comment: А. Критиковать Вас или Ваши ответы — у меня кишка тонка. Б. Я просто хотела обратить Ваше внимание на небрежности в тексте, который Вы считаете особенным. В. Мне кажется, что Вы даже не посмотрели на указанные мною ошибки — иначе, думаю, была бы хоть какая-нибудь реакция на них. Г. Слова, приведённые в Вашем ответе, _никак_ не являются цитатой: они изменены.  Д. Я тоже практически всегда ссылаюсь на _правильные_ источники. **Е, Ё, Ж... А вообще — с праздником Вас, Sharon!** Вернулись разногорластые чайки, угорелые белки накручивают спирали на соснах — значит, весна!

Comment: 1. Римма, извините меня, я действительно невнимательно прочитала тот ваш ответ и обещаю исправиться. 2. И вас – с праздником и с наступающей весной!  А также привет белочкам и чайкам, обязательно передайте! (А вот наши мужчины на форуме не поздравляют нас и цветов не дарят, а если и поздравляют, то очень оригинально – двойными и тройными штрафами.)